# How to customize toast content in UWP apps?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I am creating a toast for my UWP app. I have a requirement to add an image, text and icon (all in the same row but different columns).Is there support to add icons to toasts in UWP apps ? Looking at the documentation it seemed like icons are not supported so as a workaround I used an image of the icon instead

```
ToastContent tC = new ToastContent();
                   

                    toastContent.Visual = new ToastVisual()
                    {
                        BindingGeneric = new ToastBindingGeneric()
                        {
                            Children =
                            {
                                new AdaptiveGroup()
                                {
                                    Children =
                                    {
                                        new AdaptiveSubgroup()
                                        {
                                            Children =
                                            {
                                                new AdaptiveImage()
                                                {
                                                    Source = "Image1.png",
                                                    HintAlign = AdaptiveImageAlign.Left,
                                                    HintRemoveMargin = true,
                                                },
                                            },
                                        },
                                        new AdaptiveSubgroup()
                                        {
                                            Children =
                                            {
                                                new AdaptiveText()
                                                {
                                                    Text = "Hello world",
                                                    HintStyle = AdaptiveTextStyle.Body,
                                                },
                                                new AdaptiveImage()
                                                {
                                                    Source = "Image2.png",
                                                    HintAlign = AdaptiveImageAlign.Stretch,
                                                    HintRemoveMargin = true,
                                                },
                                            },
                                        },
                                    },
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    };

                    ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(tC.GetXml());
                    ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
```

With the above code I can see the elements show up in the same row but there are not aligned. Since I can't control the padding or margins here , how do I get these to align ?

Comment: Have you checked my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code, it seems that the second `AdaptiveGroup` contains a Text on the top of the image so these contents are not aligned.

A possbile solution is to add another `AdaptiveText` in to the first `AdaptiveGroup` but without text. Then the first `AdaptiveGroup` will looks like the same as the second `AdaptiveGroup`.  Also, you could change the [AdaptiveSubgroup.HintTextStacking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.notifications.adaptivesubgroup.hinttextstacking?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.1) property to sets the vertical alignment of this subgroup's content.

Here is the code I modified. I tried to center all the content so they looks aligned.

```
BindingGeneric = new ToastBindingGeneric()
            {
                Children =
                        {
                            new AdaptiveGroup()
                            {
                                Children =
                                {
                                    new AdaptiveSubgroup()
                                    {
                                        HintWeight=50,
                                       HintTextStacking= AdaptiveSubgroupTextStacking.Center,
                                        Children =
                                        {
                                             new AdaptiveText()
                                            {
                                                Text = "",
                                                HintStyle = AdaptiveTextStyle.Body,
                                            },

                                            new AdaptiveImage()
                                            {
                                                Source = "ms-appx:///Assets/paris.png",
                                                 HintAlign = AdaptiveImageAlign.Stretch,
                                                HintRemoveMargin = true,
                                            },
                                        },
                                    },
                                    new AdaptiveSubgroup()
                                    {
                                        HintWeight=50,
                                          HintTextStacking= AdaptiveSubgroupTextStacking.Center,
                                        Children =
                                        {
                                            
                                            new AdaptiveText()
                                            {
                                                Text = "Hello world",
                                                HintStyle = AdaptiveTextStyle.Body,
                                            },
                                            new AdaptiveImage()
                                            {
                                                Source = "ms-appx:///Assets/london.png",
                                                HintAlign = AdaptiveImageAlign.Stretch,
                                                HintRemoveMargin = true,
                                            },
                                        },
                                    },
                                },
                            },
                        },
            },
```

Comment: Thanks @Roy Li for this. It helps with the alignment but I am running into an issue where there is a huge gap between the 3 columns. If I set the HintWeight = 1, the toasts do not pop at all? Do you have any recommendations here ? Also is there a way to support font icons or glyphs in toasts ?

Comment: @novice_coder Do you mean you have 3 `AdaptiveSubgroup` now? And you are setting the `HintWeight` as 1 for all the `AdaptiveSubgroups`?

Comment: @novice_coder Since the `AdaptiveText` object doesn't have a font family property, so it is not possbile to use font icons in the `AdaptiveText`. And it the same for glyphs.

Comment: Li , yes I have 3 subgroups now and they all have a huge space between them. I set the FontWeight = 1 and that didn't help.Any way to reduce this?